# Uso correcto de localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

Buenas estoy empleando por primera vez `localstorage` y no consigo que funcione, ¿acaso lo he escrito mal?

```
for(var j=1; j<(totalInputs+1); j++){
   var resultado = $('#Titulo-'+i+'-'+j).val();
   localStorage.setItem('resultadoStorage', resultado);
   var resultadoStorage = localStorage.getItem('resultadoStorage');
   $('#Casilla-'+i+'-'+j).text(resultadoStorage);
}
```

A continuación dejo todo el código.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#Anyadir-Rutina-btn').click(function() {

    /********************************************************
     ** Hacemos aparecer el formulario del WOD
     ********************************************************/
    $('#Modal-Formulario').css('display', 'flex');


    /********************************************************
     ** BOTÓN "+ Ejercicio"
     ** Genera una nueva fila "Ejercicio" tanto en el formulario
     ** como en la tabla para visualizar el WOD
     ********************************************************/
    var valorIdFila = 4; // Contador (las 3 primeras son siempre fijas).
    $('#Anyadir-Ejercicio').click(function() {

      // 1) Creo e inserto una nueva fila en el formulario.
      var nuevaFila = '<div class="ModalFila" id="ModalFila' + valorIdFila + '"></div>';
      $('#ModalFila' + (valorIdFila - 1)).after(nuevaFila);

      // 2) Creo los campos de texto del formulario
      var ejercicio = '<input type="text" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo-' + valorIdFila + '-1" placeholder="Ejercicio">';
      var herramienta = '<input type="text" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo-' + valorIdFila + '-2" placeholder="Herramienta">';
      var series = '<input type="text" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo-' + valorIdFila + '-3" placeholder="Nº series">';
      var repeticiones = '<input type="text" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo-' + valorIdFila + '-4" placeholder="Nº repeticiones">';
      var pesoPropuesto = '<input type="text" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo-' + valorIdFila + '-5" placeholder="Peso propuesto">';
      var pesoFinal = '<input type="text" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo-' + valorIdFila + '-6" placeholder="Peso Final">';

      // 3) Los inserto en la nueva fila
      $('#ModalFila' + valorIdFila).append(ejercicio);
      $('#ModalFila' + valorIdFila).append(herramienta);
      $('#ModalFila' + valorIdFila).append(series);
      $('#ModalFila' + valorIdFila).append(repeticiones);
      $('#ModalFila' + valorIdFila).append(pesoPropuesto);
      $('#ModalFila' + valorIdFila).append(pesoFinal);


      // 4) Creo nueva fila y columnas en la tabla
      var tabla = $("#Tabla-Rutinas");
      var nuevaFila = $("<tr></tr>");

      for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        var nuevaColumna = $("<td></td>").attr({
          "class": "Casilla",
          "id": "Casilla-" + valorIdFila + "-" + (i + 1)
        });
        nuevaFila.append(nuevaColumna);
      }

      tabla.append(nuevaFila);

      // 5) Incremento contador por si quieren añadir una nueva fila.
      valorIdFila = valorIdFila + 1;

    });

    /********************************************************
     ** FUNCIÓN para eliminar los ejercicios añadidos por el
     ** botón "+ Ejercicio" en el formulario.
     ********************************************************/
    function eliminarEjerciciosExtra() {
      for (var b = 4; b < valorIdFila; b++) {
        $('#ModalFila' + b).remove();
      }
    }

    /********************************************************
     ** BOTÓN "Guardar"
     ** Se trata de recorrer todos los campos del formulario e
     ** ir escribiendo en su respectiva casilla de la tabla de 
     ** visualización del WOD.
     ** Por último esconde el formulario.
     ********************************************************/
    $('#Guardar-Formulario').click(function() {

      // 1) Miro cuantas filas tiene.
      var totalFilas = $('#Modal-Formulario').find('.ModalFila').length;

      // 2) Miro cuantas columnas tiene cada fila. 
      for (var i = 1; i < totalFilas; i++) {
        var totalInputs = $('#ModalFila' + i).find('.TextoFormulario').length;

        // 3) Obtengo el valor de capa campo del formulario y lo escribo en su
        //    respectiva posición de la tabla.
        for (var j = 1; j < (totalInputs + 1); j++) {
          var resultado = $('#Titulo-' + i + '-' + j).val();
          localStorage.setItem('resultadoStorage', resultado);
          var resultadoStorage = localStorage.getItem('resultadoStorage');
          $('#Casilla-' + i + '-' + j).text(resultadoStorage);
        }
      }

      // 4) Vacío la base del formulario (FALTA HACER), elimino los añadidos y escondo el formulario
      eliminarEjerciciosExtra();
      $('#Modal-Formulario').css('display', 'none');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
/***** Formulario insertar nuevo WOD *****/

#Modal-Formulario {
  height: auto;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #354649;
  margin: auto;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.ModalFila {
  margin: 5px 0;
}

#ModalUltimaFila {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.Inputs-Modal {
  padding: 3px;
}

.TextoFormulario {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.BtnFormulario {
  background-color: #a3c6c4;
  border-color: transparent;
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.BtnFormulario:hover {
  outline: 1px solid;
  outline-color: #FFF;
}

#Titulo1 {
  width: 80%;
}

#Titulo2 {
  width: 80%;
}

#Titulo3 {
  width: 40%;
}

#Guardar-modal-btn {
  margin-right: 5px;
}


/***** Tabla donde se muestran los WODs *****/

#Tabla-Rutinas {
  height: auto;
  width: 70%;
  border: solid 1px;
  margin: auto;
}

.Casilla {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: darkred;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Power-Contenedor">

  <!-- Tabla donde se muestran los WODs -->
  <table id="Tabla-Rutinas">
    <tr>
      <!-- Fila1 -->
      <td colspan="6" class="Casilla" id="Casilla-1-1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- Fila2 -->
      <td>Nombre</td>
      <td>Herramienta</td>
      <td>Series</td>
      <td>Repeticiones</td>
      <td>Peso propuesto</td>
      <td>Peso final</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- Fila3 -->
      <td colspan="6" class="Casilla" id="Casilla-2-1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Fila4">
      <!-- Fila4 -->
      <td class="Casilla" id="Casilla-3-1"></td>
      <td class="Casilla" id="Casilla-3-2"></td>
      <td class="Casilla" id="Casilla-3-3"></td>
      <td class="Casilla" id="Casilla-3-4"></td>
      <td class="Casilla" id="Casilla-3-5"></td>
      <td class="Casilla" id="Casilla-3-6"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <!-- Formulario para insertar nuevo WOD -->
  <div id="Modal-Formulario">
    <div class="ModalFila" id="ModalFila1">
      <input type="text" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo-1-1" placeholder="Título">
    </div>
    <div class="ModalFila" id="ModalFila2">
      <input type="text" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo-2-1" placeholder="Objetivo">
    </div>
    <div class="ModalFila" id="ModalFila3">
      <input type="text" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo-3-1" placeholder="Ejercicio">
      <input type="text" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo-3-2" placeholder="Herramienta">
      <input type="text" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo-3-3" placeholder="Nº Series">
      <input type="text" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo-3-4" placeholder="Nº Repeticiones">
      <input type="text" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo-3-5" placeholder="Peso propuesto">
      <input type="text" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo-3-6" placeholder="Peso final">
    </div>
    <div class="ModalFila" id="ModalUltimaFila">
      <input type="button" class="Inputs-Modal BtnFormulario" id="Guardar-Formulario" value="Guardar">
      <input type="Button" class="Inputs-Modal BtnFormulario" value="Cancelar">
      <input type="button" class="Inputs-Modal BtnFormulario" value="+ Objetivo">
      <input type="button" class="Inputs-Modal BtnFormulario" value="- Objetivo">
      <input type="button" class="Inputs-Modal BtnFormulario" id="Anyadir-Ejercicio" value="+ Ejercicio">
      <input type="button" class="Inputs-Modal BtnFormulario" id="Borrar-Ejercicio" value="- Ejercicio">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Btn para hacer aparecer formulario "nuevo WOD" -->
  <div id="Anyadir-Rutina-Box">
    <a href="#" id="Anyadir-Rutina-btn"> Añadir entreno </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Cuando refresco la página con F5, me desaparece aquello que tenía escrito.

¿A que se puede deber?

Salud!

Comment: En ese for lo que está haciendo es machacar el item  resultadoStorage de localstorage, que deseas hacer realmente?Explicalo y  pon el código  si puedes para intentar ayudarte

Comment: @IsmaelCarvajal Ya puse todo el código, pensé que no haría falta. Lo que hago es obtener el valor que se ha escrito en los inputs y trasladarlos a una tabla. Y lo hice con localstorage para que así, esa tabla se quede escrita una vez cerremos.

Answer (score 1):

¡Hola! Veo que estás intentando guardar muchos inputs en un localStorage, el problema es que lo estás sobrescribiendo cada vez, lo que sucede es que **localStorage.getItem('resultadoStorage');** quedará con el último valor del loop, que puede ser un valor vacío. Creo que el siguiente código puede ayudarte para lo que quieres hacer:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var i=1;
  var resultados = [];
  for(var j=1; j<(10+1); j++){
    var resultado = j%3;
    resultados.push(resultado);
  }
  localStorage.setItem('resultadoStorage', JSON.stringify(resultados));
  var resultadoStorage = localStorage.getItem('resultadoStorage');
  console.log(resultadoStorage);
  console.log(JSON.parse(resultadoStorage));
</script>
```

Lo hice de esa forma debido a que no tengo tus inputs para probar (tienes que cambiar el j%3 por el valor de tus inputs). Primero estoy asignando todos los valores a un arreglo, al que le aplico stringify, ya que no se pueden guardar arreglos en localStorage, luego lo muestro en consola de dos formas, como string y transformándolo en JSON.

La idea de LocalStorage es que si actualizas el sitio y llamas a **localStorage.getItem('resultadoStorage');** tendrás disponibles los mismos datos que guardaste antes. Lo que se busca con localStorage es hacer que los datos no se pierdan con las actualizaciones de sitio, de esa forma puedes conservar datos de la navegación de tus usuarios.

**Es importante no guardar información sensible en localStorage, es muy fácil atacar estos datos, debes tener cuidado al usarlo.**

Eso ¡Mucha suerte y éxito!

Comment: Buenas tardes Sebastian, quería preguntar ¿En el LocalStorage es correcto guardar por ejemplo, muchos aritculos de varias secciones de un sistema de restaurantes o sólo se debe usar para guarda información concreta del usuario (la sesión, ID, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

el for se ejecuta cuando carga la pagina o esta dentro de una función?

- Lo que puede pasar es que tu variable **resultado** este vació, puedes fijar un valor   `localStorage.setItem('resultadoStorage', 'test - Local Storage');`.
- No entiendo la razón por la que invocas   **localStorage.setItem()** y a la siguiente linea invocas el get localStorage.**getItem**().

sabes como funciona el localStorage?

Comment: Puse todo el código, pero sí, está dentro de una función. Los invoco tan seguidos, porque básicamente cojo el valor de un input y lo meto en una tabla. Lo que yo quiero es que al cerrar la página y mañana volver, eso siga escrito en la tabla.